# Prevent overlaps of text when hover on ellipted span

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to build a series of div that would contained multiple spans with long text. Part of the text is ellipted but when going over, the newly visible part overlaps the next span.

Here is an example :

```css
  div.one {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  }

  div.one span {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 75px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  }
  
  div.one span:hover{
  height: auto;
  overflow:visible;
  }
```

```html
 <div class="one">
  <span>Some example of a very very long text</span>
  <span>Some example of a very very long text</span>
  <span>Some example of a very very long text</span>
  <span>Some example of a very very long text</span>
  <span>Some example of a very very long text</span>
  <span>Some example of a very very long text</span>   
 </div>
```

I tried to change the color background on hover so it hides the background text, but it doesn't expand to the newly visible text. How should I handle this ? What are the options ? These are my questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `width:auto; display:block;` when hover. It will force next span to move forward and create enough space for your current text.

```css
div.one {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

div.one span {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 75px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

div.one span:hover{
  height: auto;
  overflow:visible;
  width:auto;
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
  <span>Some example of a very very long text</span>
  <span>Some example of a very very long text</span>
  <span>Some example of a very very long text</span>
  <span>Some example of a very very long text</span>
  <span>Some example of a very very long text</span>
  <span>Some example of a very very long text</span>   
</div>
```

Hope this helps:)

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't quite tell what your intended result was so here's two versions: the top row has each span expand horizontally to display its full text and overlay on top of the span next to it. The second row has the text expanding vertically instead.

For the first version to work properly, you'll notice there's the `direction: rtl;` property being used on the parent container - this causes the contents of this `div` (also note that the `span` children must be `inline-block` instead of `float` for this to work) to display in reverse order. Doing this lets the overlap work properly, in that it sets the `z-index` priority higher for each preceding element.

```css
div.one {
  display: block;
    direction: rtl;
    float: left;
    height: 30px;
  }

  div.one > span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 75px;
  margin-right: 10px;
    direction: ltr;
    position: relative;
  }
    
    div.one > span > span {
      width: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 2;
      display: block;
      overflow: hidden;
      white-space: nowrap;
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
      background: white;
    }
  
  div.one > span:hover > span {
  width: auto;
  overflow: visible;
  }
    
  div.two {
    display: block;
    clear: left;
    padding-top: 20px;
  }
  div.two > span {
  float: left;
  width: 75px;
  margin-right: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    background: white;
 }
  div.two > span:hover {
    height: auto;
    display: block;
    white-space: normal;
  }
```

```html
<div class="one">
  <span><span>Some example of a very very long text</span></span>
  <span><span>Some example of a very very long text</span></span>
  <span><span>Some example of a very very long text</span></span>
  <span><span>Some example of a very very long text</span></span>
  <span><span>Some example of a very very long text</span></span>
  <span><span>Some example of a very very long text</span></span>
 </div>
  
  <div class="two">
  <span>Some example of a very very long text</span>
  <span>Some example of a very very long text</span>
  <span>Some example of a very very long text</span>
  <span>Some example of a very very long text</span>
  <span>Some example of a very very long text</span>
  <span>Some example of a very very long text</span>
 </div>
```

Comment: I kind of like your solution (covering up instead of pushing). Yet it doesn't work when implemented on my website. Not sure why, but the other answers worked on a single copy/paste in my source code.

Comment: @PaulEndymion Did you also change the HTML structure? In the first row, it relies on a second nested `span` to achieve that effect.

Comment: I didn't so it works now but doesn't fit my project. Anyway, thank you for your time  (upvote).

Comment: @PaulEndymion Welcome, any time. Good luck with the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
    <div class="one">
        <span>Some example of a very very long text</span>
        <span>Some example of a very very long text</span>
        <span>Some example of a very very long text</span>
        <span>Some example of a very very long text</span>
        <span>Some example of a very very long text</span>
        <span>Some example of a very very long text</span>   
    </div>

    div.one {
        width: 100%;
    }

    div.one span {
        display: inline-block;
        overflow: hidden;
        white-space: nowrap;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        width: 75px;
        margin-right: 10px;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

    div.one span:hover{
        width: auto;
        overflow: visible;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
  div.one {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  }

  div.one span {
        dysplay: block;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 10%;
  }
  
  div.one span:hover{
        cursor:pointer;
        width: 250px;
         transition: width 2s;
  height: 20px;
  overflow:visible;
  }
```

```html
 <div class="one">
  <span>Some example of a very very long text</span>
  <span>Some example of a very very long text</span>
  <span>Some example of a very very long text</span>
  <span>Some example of a very very long text</span>
  <span>Some example of a very very long text</span>
  <span>Some example of a very very long text</span>   
 </div>
```